# Returning multi-dimensional associative array with mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to return a multidimensional associative array from my MySql Database with the Format

```
$array[0]['user']
$array[0]['dateCompleted']
$array[0]['etc']
$array[1]['user']
$array[1]['dateCompleted']
$array[1]['etc']
```

...

Here is my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);
//Clean input
$idUser = trim($_SESSION['tmp01']);
/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user, dateCompleted, workType, workPrice FROM workDone WHERE user=? ORDER BY dateCompleted DESC");

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idUser);

$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->result_metadata();
$fields = array();
$row = array();
$rows = array();

$fields[0] = &$stmt;
$count = 1;

// this dynamically creates an array where each key is the name of the field. 
while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
    $fields[$count] = &$row[$field->name];
    $count++;
}

// this calls bind_result() to each member of this $row array  
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $row);       //<--problem                      
while ($stmt->fetch())
    array_push($rows, $row);

$results = (count($rows) == 0) ? false : $rows;
//print_r($results);
return $results;

$stmt->close();
```

It works when I use the SQL statement `"SELECT * FROM users ...")`, but I overrun my servers memory by doing that. Instead I use the above code, but what it does it return a the same instance for each row I have.

In other words if I have four distinct rows in my MySQL database, it will return the first row four times.

P.S.

My server does not have mysqlnd enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks to be correct, but you seem to be passing incorrect arguments to `call_user_func_array`. Try this:

```
$data = $stmt->result_metadata();
$fields = array();
$currentrow = array();
$results = array();

// Store references to keys in $currentrow
while ($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
  $fields[] = &$currentrow[$field->name];
}

// Bind statement to $currentrow using the array of references
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'), $fields);

// Iteratively refresh $currentrow array using "fetch", store values from each row in $results array
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $results[$i] = array(); //this is supposed to be outside the foreach
  foreach($currentrow as $key => $val) {
    $results[$i][$key] = $val;
  }
  $i++;
}

return $results;
```

Comment: When I use the above code, it only returns an array with a nested array containing only the workPrice key and none of the other fields. Array ( [0] => Array ( [workPrice] => 25.00 ) [1] => Array ( [workPrice] => 25.00 ) [2] => Array ( [workPrice] => 100.00 ) )

Comment: @AlexHeuman I actually just spotted a syntax error in my code (extra parenthesis in `call_user_func_array`). That shouldn't have run at all.

Comment: Right, I spotted the same syntax and removed it before I implemented it, my only problem is the not being able to return all of the fields into an array, but only the last one. Looking at the code, I'm unable to understand what to change.

Comment: @AlexHeuman Are the `workPrice` values correct according to the data present in the table? I'm trying to figure it out, but as a wild guess, try using `call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'), $currentrow);`

Comment: @AlexHeuman Try using `call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'), $currentrow);` (this is identical to what you were using before)

Comment: I still am getting the same problem as when using $fields.

Comment: @AlexHeuman Wow, what an idiotic mistake. I was resetting the `results[n]` array during every iteration when iterating over the values in `currentrow`.  Fixed it now.

Comment: Alright, working like it was never broken. Thanks for all of your help and debugging. It's always the smallest things that cause the biggest problems.